# Parsing argument list specifying a player to be added

Tags: java

I want to start off by saying sorry, I wasn't able to search for this problem as I couldn't exactly describe it myself.

I have a series of if-statements to account for each scenario. As you can see in the mammoth block of code below, I want arguments to come in any order. **How, if possible, can I shorten this?**

```
if(args[1].startsWith("u:") && args[2].startsWith("r:") && args[3].startsWith("l:")){ // u / r / l
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[1].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[2].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[3].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("r:") && args[2].startsWith("l:") && args[3].startsWith("u:")){ // r / l / u
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[3].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[1].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[2].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("l:") && args[2].startsWith("u:") && args[3].startsWith("r:")){ // l / u / r
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[2].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[3].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[1].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("u") && args[2].startsWith("l:") && args[3].startsWith("r:")){ // u / l / r
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[1].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[3].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[2].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("l:") && args[2].startsWith("r:") && args[3].startsWith("u:")){ // l / r / u
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[2].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[2].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[1].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("r:") && args[2].startsWith("u:") && args[3].startsWith("l:")){ // r / u / l
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[2].split(":")[1]);
    String r = args[1].split(":")[1];
    String l = args[3].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It will facilitate our understanding if you can explain the background to these `if` statements too, so that perhaps we can too suggest any 'larger-picture' solutions that are appropriate. :)

Comment: @h.j.k. Well I'm just going through old code and re-writing it. For my case, I highly doubt there are any 'larger-picture' solutions.

Comment: @Spedwards I'd bet you're wrong. You seem to be doing some command line parsing and that's a problem solved many times before.

Comment: @Spedwards when I said 'larger-picture' solutions, I was thinking along the lines of how costly is `player.getServer()`? Can that be called once? Can we inline the variables' assignments to `Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player)`? ;)

Comment: I think the bigger problem is, not only that you had difficulty writing the code, you also had difficulty describing the purpose of the code to us in plain words while posing this question. Suppose that you knew no Java, but had to ask a programmer friend to write the code for you. How would you explain the task to be solved? Write that out first, _then_ try to translate it into code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to cover all possible combinations of `u: r: l:` parameters.
In your implementation,
the purpose of each `if` statement is to figure out the order of these parameters and act accordingly.

A good first step can be to create a method that processes parameters given in the *canonical order*.
It doesn't matter what is the *canonical order*,
but once you define it, it will help you, for example:

```
void parseArgs(String playerParam, String rParam, String lParam) {
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(playerParam.split(":")[1]);
    String r = rParam.split(":")[1];
    String l = lParam.split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
}
```

With this method, your `if` branches can be simplified, for example:

```
if(args[1].startsWith("u:") && args[2].startsWith("r:") && args[3].startsWith("l:")){ // u / r / l
    parseArgs(args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    return true;
}else if(args[1].startsWith("r:") && args[2].startsWith("l:") && args[3].startsWith("u:")){ // r / l / u
    parseArgs(args[3], args[1], args[2]);
    return true;
} // ... and so on
```

In other words, the `if` branches effectively perform *translation*:

- from the detected ordering to the canonical ordering
- from meaningless `args[...]` values to meaningful parameter names (`playerParam`, `rParam`, ...)

Speaking of meaningful, `r` and `l` are very poor variable names,
all this would be a lot more readable if you improved them.

This is still far from good, because there are a lot of wasted operations here:

- If the ordering was `r:u:l:`, then 6 `startswith` calls will be evaluated before reaching the last `if` branch.
- Writing out all the combinations is tedious, and inevitably error prone:

  - You might forget a combination
  - You might accidentally write the same combination twice
  - You might accidentally write the wrong `args[...]` values when handling a combination
- What if you have to add more parameters `x:` and `y:`? Your number of combinations will explode and you'll go nuts
- All those `startswith` calls are a lot of duplicated code
- Notice the overlap in the logic of `startswith` and `split`: you could split in advance, and use `equals` instead of `startswith`

Instead of listing all combinations, it's better to parse the arguments list in a loop:

```
Player p = null;
String r = null;
String l = null;
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    String arg = args[i];

    String[] parts = arg.split(":");
    String key = parts[0];
    String value = parts[1];

    if (key.equals("u")) {
        p = player.getServer().getPlayer(value);
    } else if (key.equals("r")) {
        r = value;
    } else if (key.equals("l")) {
        l = value;
    }
}
if (p != null && r != null && l != null) {
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

This is equivalent to your code above, and easily scalable to support more parameters if needed.
Notice how I used local variables to give meaning to meaningless things,
for example `key` to refer to `parts[0]`, and `value` to refer to `parts[1]`.

Comment: This is a great answer. I just want to add, mostly for OP, that in practice you should add more error handling: what if there is not exactly 3 args, what if the format of the parameters is not "X:Y", and so on ...

Comment: @coredump This is a great comment ;-) In fact, it would stand well on its own as an answer, something I'd definitely upvote! (Especially if you add example code to handle the situation gracefully.)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, don't ever write code like this... you know it can be done better, so don't waste your time.

Moreover, you can be sure, you'll make some errors there, e.g., this looks wrong:

```
Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[2].split(":")[1]);
String r = args[2].split(":")[1];
```

as you're using `args[2]` twice.

---

It's actually very trivial:

```
String[] inputs = {args[1], args[2], args[3]);
Arrays.sort(inputs);
if (inputs[0].startsWith("l:") && inputs[1].startsWith("r:") && inputs[2].startsWith("u:")) {
    Player p = player.getServer().getPlayer(inputs[2].split(":")[1]);
    String r = inputs[1].split(":")[1];
    String l = inputs[0].split(":")[1];
    Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player);
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

A possibly even simpler alternative would be to go through the args and always fill the appropriate data slot (`p`, `r`, and `l`). After processing all three args, all slots must be filled, otherwise the input is wrong.

---

There's much more to say... e.g., your repetitive

```
args[2].split(":")[1]
```

should be replaced by a method. You also most probably don't want to allow args like `l:12:34:567` (or you don't want to lose the part after the second colon), so don't use split.

Actually, I guess, you need some command line parser... there are at least 10 such things in Java freely available.

Comment: Nice, all-rounded answer! Supplementary info: `split()` accepts a `limit` parameter, so technically speaking OP can do something like `args[2].split(":", 2)`, if that's really the intended consequence...

Comment: @h.j.k. Right. It's just that `split` is strange (see Guava's `Splitter`), so I always avoid it. And something like `substring(2)` would be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very similar to other ones, apart that I try to take care of ill-formed input.

### Remarks

- I throw (unchecked) `IllegalArgumentException` exceptions, but you could use your own set of checked exceptions, if you prefer.
- Likewise, here, exceptions are never catched and goes directly back to the user: in a real application, you might prefer to print error messages.
- I use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes to better specify and extract the intended input fields. The regex for each argument is the following one:

  ```
  "([url]):(.*)"
  ```
- I use a `switch` on a character, using `m.groups(1).charAt(0)`
- The `switch` has a default case in order to catch programming errors, if the `PATTERN`'s first group's set of characters (`[url]`) differs from characters recognized by the `switch`.
- Parts of the code are only there in order to mock the surrounding elements, in order to make the compiler happy (I actually tested the code). Unfortunately, we are given little information about how are elements structured in OP's actual source code, so for example, we don't know what `player` actually is nor where it is initialized.

### Other problems

Even though I don't know exactly how everything is organized, there is some code-smell surrounding the following parts:

- The code that parses arguments has a reference to some `player`. I don't know why it is necessary, but this is suspicious.Maybe a more precise name would be preferable (`mainPlayer`, `localPlayer`, `currentPlayer`, ...)
- `Config.addPlayer(p, r, l, player)`

  - We never know what `r` and `l` stand for, nor why they are of type `String` (Strings are generally a code-smell by themselves, but we never know, maybe this is required here).
  - `Config` is not an object, but a class, for which we call a static function. This might be justified, but maybe you could have a `Config` interface and call a method on the actual implementation (decoupling).
  - Is `Config` also a factory that creates `Player` instances? It seems that the `Config` class has too many responsabilities,  *as if it were the junction point for the entire space-time continuum* (or maybe just an amazing coincidence).

### Full code

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

/* HELPER CLASSES TO MAKE EVERYTHING COMPILE */

class Config {
    public static void addPlayer(Player u, String r, String l, Player p) {
        System.out.println(u+r+" "+l+p);
    }
}

class Player {
    public final String u;
    public Player(String u) {
        this.u = u;
    }
    Server getServer(){
        return OptionParser.SERVER;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + u + "]";
    }
}

class Server {
    public Player getPlayer(String u) {
        return new Player(u);
    }
}

/* HERE WE GO */

public class OptionParser {
    public static final Server SERVER = new Server();
    private static final String EXPECTED_FORMAT_MESSAGE =
        "Expected format: u:<name> l:<XXX> r:<YYY>";

    private static final Pattern PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("([url]):(.*)");

    private final Player player = new Player("Test");

    public void addPlayerFromArgs(String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(EXPECTED_FORMAT_MESSAGE);
        }

        Player u = null;
        String r = null;
        String l = null;

        for(String arg : args) {
            Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(arg);
            if (m.find()) {
                String value = m.group(2);
                switch(m.group(1).charAt(0)){
                case 'u' : 
                    u = player.getServer().getPlayer(value);
                    break;
                case 'r' :
                    r = value;
                    break;
                case 'l' :
                    l = value;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException
                        ("Bug: either fix the regex pattern or the switch");
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(EXPECTED_FORMAT_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        /* If the user provides a key twice, like "u:alice u:bob", we
         * will fail below */

        for (Object object : new Object[]{u,r,l}) {
            if (object == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(EXPECTED_FORMAT_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        Config.addPlayer(u, r, l, player);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        OptionParser op = new OptionParser();
        op.addPlayerFromArgs(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work! I recommend some corrections: 1. the standard ordering for modifiers would be `public static final`, `private final`, etc. 2. The name `Test` evokes the idea of a unit test, which it is not, so it can be a bit confusing.

Comment: @janos Edited, thanks. I settled for `OptionParser` (Now, I wonder how OP actually named its class)